# Order by a Boolean column in SQLAlchemy using Flask

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this model:

```py
class Task(db.Model):
    ...
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=False, unique=False, nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, index=False, unique=False, default=False)
    ...
```

In my Flask endpoint I would like to use `order_by` first on the `created` date. And then afterwards based on the `active` state of the `Task`. So if `active = True` it should be sorted on that as well. Is this possible?

I tried this:

```py
@app.route('/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    all_tasks = Task.query.order_by(Task.created.desc(), Task.active).all()
    return jsonify(tasks_schema.dump(all_tasks))
```

However that is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Whats you output now and what do you want it to be?
First thought is that maybe it gets ordered by `created`, and then by `active`, which does nothing - as each `created` will be unique (as it is DateTime).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe not answer to your question, as you want to use `order_by`, but I'm using this code to order by boolean:

```py
self.items.sort(key=lambda x: (-x.active, x.name))
```